# Getting ProcessExitedException. How to spawn multiple processes on databricks notebook using torch.multiprocessing?

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, databricks, multiple-gpu, distributed-training

I am trying out distributed training in pytorch using "DistributedDataParallel" strategy on databrick notebooks (or any notebooks environment). But I am stuck with multi-processing on a databricks notebook environment.

Problem: **I want to spwan multiple processes on databricks notebook** using *torch.multiprocessing*. I have extracted out the problem from main code for easier understanding of the problem.

```
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

def train():
  print("hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  processes = 4
  mp.spawn(train, args=(), nprocs=processes)
  print("completed")
```

Exception:

```
ProcessExitedException: process 1 terminated with exit code 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProcessExitedException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2917251930623656> in <module>
     19 if __name__ == '__main__':
     20   processes = 4
---> 21   mp.spawn(train, args=(), nprocs=processes)
     22   print("completed")
     23 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py in spawn(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method)
    228                ' torch.multiprocessing.start_processes(...)' % start_method)
    229         warnings.warn(msg)
--> 230     return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py in start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method)
    186 
    187     # Loop on join until it returns True or raises an exception.
--> 188     while not context.join():
    189         pass
    190
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: Are you using Jupyter notebook for your code? If so, try running it as a simple Python file instead. I had the same issue and turns out everything was fine except Jupyter (I don't know why yet, might dig deeper later)